# Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: set-theory

As you know if **A** and **B** are sets then,

A × B = {(a1, b1), (a1,b2), ...}

and consider the proof the R is not in one-to-one correspondence with N

also consider n is a member of N
and r of R

we can show that:
N × R ={(n1, r1), ..., (n2 , r2), ..., (n3 , r3), ...}

we will ran out of *n*s but not *r*s

so we can show that we can't create the N × R set.

but here's another approach:

consider n is a member of N

and r of R

we can create N × R like this:

N × R

= {(n1, r1), (n1 , r2), ...

, (n2, r1), (n2 , r2), ...,

(n3, r1), (n3 , r2), ...}

so which approach is correct?

Is N × R is uncreatable?

Comment: Your notion of cartesian product seems wrong. A × B = { (a,b) | a∈A and b∈B}

Comment: How much do you know about the axioms of set theory? Sets are "creatable" if their descriptions can be expressed using the axioms, and certainly the set $\mathbb N \times \mathbb R$ can be described in that manner (using, for example, the formula in the comment of @MichaelCarey). I'll say, though, that attempting to list the elements using $...$ is NOT a description that is allowed by the axioms.

Comment: I know a little bit, could you name some resources to study math?
also thanks for your answer

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The [tag:cantor-set] tag does not seem appropriate for this question

Comment: you're right @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Both setups have errors, but in the second case your intuition is closer.  Points in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$ are all $(1,r)$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$, together with all $(2,r)$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$, etc.  But you can't write $(1,r_1),(1,r_2),\ldots$ as you have because $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable, i.e. can't be listed like that.  Otherwise you are approaching the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Math SE.

> we will ran out of $n$s but not $r$s

No, we won't run out of $n$s. There are infinitely many of them. There are proofs that $\mathbb{R}$ is not in one-to-one correspondence (bijection) with $\mathbb{N}$, but they do not rely on $\mathbb{N}$ being finite (since it isn't).

The Cartesian product $A\times B$ of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set of all *2-tuples* $(a, b)$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So, the Cartesian product $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}$ is the set of all $(n, r)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$. A perfectly valid set!

It has uncountably many elements, since there is an injection $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}$ (say, by mapping $r$ to $(1, r)$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$), and $\mathbb{R}$ has uncountably many elements. But it is not countable, since there is no injection $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{N}$. Neither of these facts really show that $|\mathbb{N}|\neq |\mathbb{R}|$ though. It might be better if you clarified exactly what your question was!